# Remember the original object which is merely able to manage shared memory

Tags: c++, destructor, default-copy-constructor

I have a question about good C++ style:
I would like to write a class "MyClass" which has one or some pointers as members and MyClass is able to allocate memory to this pointers. I would like to use the implicit give default-copy-constructor (as well as the default-assignement-operator) to copy an instance of MyClass, so that only the pointers were copied and the new object share the data which the initial object has allocated.

My idea was to prohibit copied objects (created with copy constructor or assignment operator) to release memory (as well as allocate memory to member pointers). In order to distinguesh between copied objects and original objects (created by the constructor), I want to use the following code:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
       MyClass(): originalPtr(this) { data = new char[100000]; }
       ~MyClass() { if(originalPtr == this) delete[] data; }
private:
       MyClass *originalPtr;
       char *data; // shared data (not copiable)
       char otherFeatures[10]; // individual data (copiable)
};
```

Would this solution (using the comparison with the `this`-pointer) a good style for such a purpose (e.g. parsing an object by call by value) or is it risky? Of course, I assume that the original object live always longer than the copied objects.

Thank you!

Comment: If the original always lives longer than the copies, why copy at all instead of handing out references?

Comment: In order to provide individual data of the copies (hinted by "otherFeatures").

Comment: Why not use `shared_ptr` or the like?

Comment: Is it good style? Not so much. Would it work? Yes. Is it risky? Currently (`originalPtr` **always** `== this` in your example).

Comment: This smells like an XY-problem

Comment: As a user of your class I would always have to manually keep track of which pointer is the original and make sure it doesn't disappear before I'm done with the object, so your memory management class has no advantage over doing everything manually.

Comment: isn't std::shared_ptr for the internal pointers the easy option here?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is a bad idea. If the pointers are shared by several instances, than the one to deallocate should be the last one to die, not the original one. This differs in the sense that the original one might not be the one to die, which would cause all others to be pointing at garbage. Even though you assume that it's the last one to die, you need to realise that the inner workings of a class should not rely on external assumptions. That is, the class has no guarantees on how its life span is managed by the rest of the implementation, so it shouldn't make assumptions.

In this situation you should track references to your data. The basic idea is to keep track of how many copies of the class you have. As soon as that count reaches zero, you are free to release that memory; the last copy has just died. Fortunately for you, [STL already provides such an implementation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). These are known as [Smart Pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer). There are others, such as [std::unique_ptr](http://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), which makes the opposite by ensuring that the data is owned only by a single instance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, assuming the general case, where the original object does not die at last. I like the idea to just count the instances. For example one could use such a concept:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   MyClass(): countOfInstances(new int())
   {
       ++*countOfInstances;
       data = new char[100000];
   }

   ~MyClass()
   {
       --*countOfInstances;
       if(!countOfInstances)
       {
           delete[] data;
           delete countOfInstances;
       }
   }    

   MyClass(const MyClass &other) // analogous for the assignment operator
   {
       countOfInstances = other.countOfInstances;
       data = other.data;
       otherFeatures = other.otherFeatures;
       ++*countOfInstances;
   }

private:
   int *countOfInstances;
   char *data; // shared data (not copiable)
   char otherFeatures; // individual data (copiable)
```

};

Here, one should also make sure that the shared memory is completely allocated before allowing to make copies.